# Is it possible to assign new id to jstree nodes copied?

Tags: drag-and-drop, jstree

I have two jstree and dnd nodes from one to another using copy_node api. But copied nodes don't have original ids (json data ids). Auto generated ids assign them like 'j2_1'. I have original ids and want to change them with original ids. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

I know, it's been a while since you posted this question. However, I am working right now with jstree and had almost the same "problem".

I used `data.original.id` to get the original id of my copied item.
And I changed the id using `$("#jstree").jstree(true).set_id(data.node,new_id);`. In my case, I wanted my new id to involve the original one.

Here is my code block:

```
// this function is called, if I copy and paste a node
  $("#jstree").bind('copy_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
        var old_id= data.original.id;
        // I just made a new id out of the old one, e.g. appending a number
        var new_id = old_id+"1";
        $("#jstree").jstree(true).set_id(data.node,new_id);
```